# Model toy gun stock from image

Tags: modeling, image, sculpting, faces

[image]

I am trying to learn Blender and a friend asked if I could recreate this gun stock on a toy gun, I thought it would be easy. I was wrong. I've taken 3 pictures, imported them, created the profile from the side view (image below), extruded it out and that's as far as I can get before I totally destroy the profile trying to shape it. the problem I'm having is the base is wider than the top and I need to skew the profile so it angles. I couldn't find a tool to do this. I guess my newbie question is what is the best wat to recreate this in blender, am I on the right path and if so how do I angle this once I have my profile the way I want it??

Sorry if I'm not throwing out the correct terms, Like I said, total newbie here

Comment: hello, could you please show what you've tried? because it's hard to understand why you've failed and it will help to propose a solution

Comment: This might be a good place for you to use sculpting

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for may be the *Shear* tool:

Follow the shape with some extrusions:

[image]

Extrude and mirror:

[image]

Shear in order to tilt the surface, the shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> then X in order to move the vertices along the X axis (horizontal) of your view (it would have been Y if you wanted to move them horizontally according to your view):

[image]

Then bevel, etc:

[image]